# 16.04 UPDATE several hardware unclaimed

Tags: 16.04, drivers

After updating Ubuntu 16.04, my speaker, wifi and display was not working.

Below is the output of `sudo lshw | grep UNCLAIMED`

```
*-display UNCLAIMED                                                               
    *-communication UNCLAIMED  
            *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED   
                 *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED   
                 *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED   
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED    
           *-network UNCLAIMED   
           *-generic UNCLAIMED    
                    *-usb UNCLAIMED     
        *-serial UNCLAIMED   
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED      
  *-power UNCLAIMED
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Update /etc/apt/sources.list by copying default sources.list from https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/.

After that check the respective modules and run modprobe *module*