# The devices on my motherboard stopped working under 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, sound

The builtin network port on my motherboard stopped working after I booted my PC.  I bought a new network card, as I thought it was hardware failure, but now I notice that the builtin soundcard doesn't work, and the builtin VGA has dropped down to 1024x768.  Not sure what it was before, but I know it was bigger.  There is a questioner here that seems to have a similar issue,
[16.04 update. Several Hardware unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911045/16-04-update-several-hardware-unclaimed/911186?newreg=679795279eb24c319f13a2686e960d59) although he has USB problems.   My usb are fine 
lspci shows all these devices as unclaimed
`Devices show up under lspci and lshw
        *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:cc00(size=8)
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
             description: Audio device
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:feaf8000-feafbfff
        *-network UNCLAIMED
             description: Ethernet controller
             product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
             vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
             physical id: 0
             bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
             version: c0
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:febc0000-febfffff ioport:dc00(size=128)`

I have just noticed that I had an error when I did apt-get upgrade with package linux-firmware.  The linux-firmware package seemed to apply OK, but later I got an error.  I didn't manage to capture the log sorry, but it was "problem with linux firmware...  dpkg(1).  Root cause seemed to be my /boot partition was full.  I cleaned that up using apt-get autoremove.  apt-get upgrade reran successfully after that but didn't do anything.  I rebooted, and still no soundcard.  Is it related?

Comment: Is it UEFI with Secure Boot on? Try disabling it before anything else.

Comment: It is BIOS.  No secure boot

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of sorted.  I went back to kernel 93 and it is all OK again.  I'll post what I did here in case any fellow know-nothings read this
If a device shows as unclaimed under lshw, then it means there is no driver found for it

I found the name of the driver module for my network device after a bit of googling, it was atl1c

I tried to load atl1c using   **sudo modprobe atl1c**
which returned message
     **not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-96-generic**

modprobe searches for modules in /lib/modules/vvvv-generic  where vvvv is the kernel version in use.

You can display the current kernel version using uname -a

I found versions of atl1c in

/lib/modules/4.4.0-**93**-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1c/atl1c.ko

/lib/modules/4.4.0-**92**-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1c/atl1c.ko

but none in 96.  Actually /lib/modules/4.4.0-**96**-generic had way less modules in it compared to 92 and 93

So I think that ubuntu tried to auto-upgrade from kernel 93 to 96 at some point and it failed because /boot was full.  But kernel 96 became the default for reboot, so the next reboot caused a problem.
I would like to know how to rerun the 96 upgrade at some point, but that is probably better done as a separate question